# Why does my WebForms report viewer not display icon resources?

Tags: model-view-controller, reporting, service, reportviewer

I am trying to integrate the SSRS WebForms report viewer into an ASP.NET MVC2 app.  The viewer comes up, but none of the javascript is evaluated.  It looks like all of the javascript and icon resources come out of calls to the "Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" pseudo url.  My MVC app is ignoring calls to .axd URI's, but I get tons of javascript errors in the page that's hosting the report viewer.  Is there something else that I need to do to get the calls to the .axd handler to work?  That particular handler is in my web.config and it looks like this:

```
  <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
   validate="false" />
```

For what it's worth, our SSRS is SQL2005, but I am using the SQL2008 report viewer.  Do I have to use the SQL2005 reportviewer web control?

Thanks,
Matthew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I didn't set up the .axd HttpHandler in the correct place in the web.config.  I had modified the IIS6  section, but not the IIS7  section.  Works like a champ now.